# Reverse of number of integer inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, reverse

```
enter_inputs=int(input())
for i in range(enter_inputs):
   rev=0
   while i>0:
       rev=(rev*10)+i%10
       i=i//10
   print(rev)
```

I am trying to get the reverse of a number in python but I am getting EOFError: EOF when reading a line why?

I guess my logic is correct.

Comment: yes,I am trying to run a codechef program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using using Python Man!, There would be inbuilt-functions for these basic uses.

```
number = int(input())
print(int(str(number)[::-1]))
```

Comment: i know the above logic too..but i was trying using very method

Answer (score 1):

To reverse a number can be done easily by using a list and then casting the result to int

```
enter_inputs=input() #input 12345
print(int("".join([i for i in enter_inputs if i.isnumeric()][::-1])))
```

Output

```
54321
```

This will take the input and `split` each number init after that it will reverse the order `join` the list and will cast it to int.